# BelongsTo relationship returns null when using relation name "user"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-5.5

When creating a simple one-to-one relationship in Laravel 5.5, `$person->user` is returning a `null` value whenever I use the method/relation name `user`. If I change the name to `foo`, `User`, or `login` the code seems to work fine. This is the second project I've had this same issue on. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

In Person model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
public function foo() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
public function getUser() {
    if ($this->user_id) {
        return User::find($this->user_id);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In PersonTest:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$person = factory(Person::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);

// This works                 
$this->assertTrue( $person->getUser()->is($user) );

// This works
$this->assertTrue( !is_null($person->foo) );
if ( $person->foo ) {
    $this->assertTrue( $person->foo->is($user) );
}

// This fails
$this->assertTrue( !is_null($person->user) );
if ( $person->user ) {
    $this->assertTrue( $person->user->is($user) );
}
```

By request, here is all of the code relating to Person, 
Entire App\Models\Person.php:

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Asset;
use App\Traits\HasGuid;
use App\Traits\HasNotes;
use App\Traits\HasModifiedBy;
use App\Traits\HasAttachments;
use App\Traits\HasRelationships;
use App\Transformers\PersonTransformer;
use App\Models\Abstracts\HasTypeModelAbstract;
use App\Models\Interfaces\HasTypeModelInterface;

class Person extends HasTypeModelAbstract implements HasTypeModelInterface {

    use HasModifiedBy,
        HasNotes,
        HasAttachments,
        HasRelationships;

    protected $fillable = [
        'person_type_id',
        'email',
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'user_id',
        'modified_by_user_id',
        'audited_at',
        'custom_attributes'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'custom_attributes' => 'json',
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'modified_by_user_id' => 'integer',
        'person_type_id' => 'integer'
    ];
    protected $dates = [
        'audited_at'
    ];

    public static $transformer = PersonTransformer::class;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(PersonType::class, 'person_type_id');
    }

    public function assets() {
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class, 'person_id');
    }
```

Traits:

```
trait HasNotes {

    protected static function bootHasNotes() {
        static::deleting(function ($instance) {
            $instance->notes->each(function ($note) {
                $note->delete();
            });
        });
    }

    public function notes() {
        return $this->morphMany(Note::class, 'notable');
    }

}

trait HasModifiedBy {

    protected static function bootHasModifiedBy() {
        static::saving(function ($instance) {
            $instance->modified_by_user_id = Auth::id();
        });
    }

    public function modifiedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'modified_by_user_id');
    }

}

trait HasAttachments {

    protected static function bootHasAttachments() {

        static::deleting(function ($instance) {
            $instance->attachments->each(function ($attachment) {
                $attachment->delete();
            });
        });
    }

    public function attachments() {
        return $this->morphMany(Attachment::class, 'attachable');
    }

}

trait HasRelationships {

    protected static function bootHasRelationships()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($instance) {
            Relation::forObject( $instance )->delete();
        });
    }


    public function related() { ...[long polymorphic relationship here]... }
```

/App/Models/Abstracts/HasTypeModelAbstract

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

// This thing just appends some custom attributes dynamically in the JSON and array forms. And no, 'user' is not a custom attribute key.

abstract class HasTypeModelAbstract extends Model {

public function newFromBuilder($attributes = array(), $connection = NULL) {
    $instance = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes);
    $instance->appendCustomAttributes();
    return $instance;
}

protected function appendCustomAttributes() {
    $this->append( $this->getCustomAttributesFromType() );
}

public function getCustomAttributesFromType() {
    if ($this->type) {
        return $this->type->custom_attributes ?
                array_keys((array) $this->type->custom_attributes) : [];
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

protected function setCustomAttributesFromType($attributes = array()) {
    if ($this->type) {
        $custom_attribute_keys = $this->getCustomAttributesFromType();
        $custom_attributes = (array) $this->custom_attributes ?: [];
        foreach ($custom_attribute_keys as $key) {
            $attributes[$key] = array_get($custom_attributes, $key);
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}

protected function addMutatedAttributesToArray(array $attributes, array $mutatedAttributes) {

    $this->appendCustomAttributes($this, $attributes);
    $attributes = $this->setCustomAttributesFromType($attributes);
    return parent::addMutatedAttributesToArray($attributes, $mutatedAttributes);
}

protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value)
{
    $keys = $this->getCustomAttributesFromType();
    if ( in_array($key, $keys) ) {
        return $this->getCustomAttributeValue( $key, $value );
    }
    return parent::mutateAttribute($key, $value);
}

protected function getCustomAttributeValue($key, $value) {
    $custom_attributes = (array) $this->custom_attributes ?: [];
    return array_get($custom_attributes, $key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you have `user` column in your Person model or method `getUserAttribute` ?

Comment: Nope. And I also checked all inherited traits, etc.

Comment: Can you include the whole file with any custom traits you use?

Comment: Done. Note that 'user' is not a custom attribute key in the 'HasTypeModelAbstract' class

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest - quickly looking at the code I don't see anything wrong but it doesn't mean everything is for sure ok.

If I were you, I would try to limit Person model just to:

```
class Person extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'person_type_id',
        'email',
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'user_id',
        'modified_by_user_id',
        'audited_at',
        'custom_attributes'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'custom_attributes' => 'json',
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'modified_by_user_id' => 'integer',
        'person_type_id' => 'integer'
    ];
    protected $dates = [
        'audited_at'
    ];

    public static $transformer = PersonTransformer::class;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(PersonType::class, 'person_type_id');
    }

    public function assets() {
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class, 'person_id');
    }

}
```

and now I would verify if everything is fine. If it's fine, now you could investigate this further, add one trait and verify, add second trait and verify, finally extend from same class.

There must be bug somewhere but looking at this code it's hard do find anything

Answer (score 0):

user is reserved name in eloquent.

try User instead of user

```
public function User() {
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I know that I can change the method name. I mentioned above that it works with 'User'. Where do you find that 'user' is a reserved name in Eloquent? It's not a property on Model. I haven't been able to find any docs on it whatsoever. I'd love to see a list.